# Directadmin default php mail from (exim)

Tags: email, exim

We use a server under NAT and it hosts a domain with unvalid tld as "MI" and when we try to send a mail with phpmail at most cases we got this error in /var/log/exim/mainlog

```
2014-11-02 04:00:06 1XkV74-0006Qj-6i == *@*.* R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp defer (-44): SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<*@*.*>: host mail4.*.* [*.*.*.*]: 450 4.1.8 <*@*>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found
```

I create a file /etc/email-addresses with following content:

```
myusername: my@valid-email-address.com
```

And when I try to import it in exim.conf in **REWRITE CONFIGURATION** with following code:

```
*@myusername ${lookup{$1}lsearch{/etc/email-addresses}{$value}fail} bcfrF
```

I've got this error on "service exim restart":

```
Starting exim: 2014-11-04 19:10:37 Exim configuration error in line 505 of /etc/exim.conf:
  option setting expected: *@myusername ${lookup{$1}lsearch{/etc/email-addresses}{$value}fail} bcfrF
```

I also try to make this for all localdomains with this code:

```
*@+local_domains "${lookup{${local_part}}lsearch{/etc/email-addresses} {$value}fail}" Ffrs
```

But I also get the same error...

Is there any ideas for this? This server running CentOS 6.5 with DA 1.46.2. Exim version is 4.84.

Best regards!

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect the file you are editing is not generating the exim.conf the way you expect it to.  Take a look at the actual exim.conf to make sure that it's generating that rewrite section properly.  It should have a line that says **begin rewrite**, followed by the line you are adding.

I found I was able to replicate the same error as you if I put the line in my global config (near the beginning), in my routers, in my transports, or at the end of the file.  I got a different error if the line appeared in the ACLs.

Comment: Hi, Todd, thank you! I just add "begin rewrite" before other code in section REWRITE CONFIGURATION and now service exim restart works without any errors :) Thank you, again!